# Auto create instances of a struct

Tags: go, struct

I am running a piece of code that receives a JSON through MQTT. Every time I receive a JSON (the MQTT is always running), I want to create an instance of a struct that I have. I also want to append that instance to a list to keep track of the number of instances I have.

Here is what I have so far:

```
func VirtualDevice(client MQTT.Client, deviceID string) **VirtualDevice {
    type Device struct{
        Type        string `json:"type"`
        Value       []interface{} `json:"value"`
        CaptureTime string   `json:"capture-time"`
    }
    type VirtualDevice struct {
        Passport struct {
            MessageTopic string `json:"message-topic"`
            PrivateKey   string `json:"private-key"`
        } `json:"passport"`
        Data struct {
            Sensor []Device `json:"sensor"`
            Actuator struct {
            } `json:"actuator"`
        } `json:"data"`
    }

    sensorData := new(VirtualDevice)

    var g MQTT.MessageHandler = func(client MQTT.Client, msg MQTT.Message) {
        err := json.Unmarshal(msg.Payload(), &sensorData)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("%+v\n", sensorData) //data_update    
        }
    }
    client.Subscribe("data-update/" + deviceID, 0, g)
    return &sensorData //Error: Cannot use &sensorData (type **VirtualDevice) as type **VirtualDevice
}
```

In another file, I have this:

```
type Ctrl struct {
    Instance []*VD
}   
var device *VD
if len(sensorList.Instance) == 0 {
            device = VirtualDevice(client, deviceID)
            oldDeviceID = deviceID
            sensorList.Instance = append(sensorList.Instance, device)
        }else if oldDeviceID != deviceID{
            device = VirtualDevice(client, deviceID)
            sensorList.Instance = append(sensorList.Instance, device)

        }
        fmt.Println(*sensorList.Instance[0])
```

As you can see, I cannot return `&sensor` even though it is type `**VirtualDevice`. How can I return this and am I on the right track with what I want to achieve? (Create new instances of the same struct with each incoming JSON, and append a pointer to each instances to not lose data)

Edit: I am able to return the struct successfully, but when I print out `*sensorList.Instance[0]` I get an empty JSON. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure what the question is here - basic syntax is covered thoroughly in the Go Tour: https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1

Comment: You create a value of your struct type the same as you would in any other part of the code. I'm really not sure what you're asking as the only piece of code you're showing is an `if` statement.

Comment: And struct initialization is at https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/5. You should take the whole tour though if you're new.

Comment: Sorry if I am unclear. I know how to create an instance of a struct. But I want it so every time I receive a message, a struct is created automatically. Should I be allocating memory and appending a point to that struct in the list?

Comment: This is programming, not magic. Nothing happens automatically. You as the programmer have to determine what happens and under what circumstances. Right now, "what happens" is not clear enough to write any code. So, when you "receive a JSON" you are going to call some code to create a struct. @Peter already gave you the syntax of creating a new instance of a struct. Why is it not acceptable? What do you actually want to happen?

Comment: When I receive a JSON, I unmarshal that JSON into a struct. When I next receive another JSON, I want to also unmarshal it into the same struct (but now it has different info). But just doing that will overwrite the first struct for the first JSON. I need a way to keep the information of all the structs created and to keep track of them.

Comment: Well, then you do *not* want to unmarshal into the same struct value. Just create a new one.

Comment: I edited my post to clarify my question. @Peter the reason I don't create a new struct is because the JSON coming in all have the same structure.

Comment: Not a new struct, a new instance of the struct. Now we know what's going on: you want to unmarshal the JSON, into a new instance of the struct, and append it to your slice of structs.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes. I edited my question again, as now I am able to create the new struct but unable to append to my slice. When I print out the first element of that slice, it's empty. Any ideas of why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function can't return a `**VirtualDevice` because the type is scoped to the function. Move the `type` definitions outside of the `func`. If they are already defined outside, just remove them.

Also, I think you might be a bit confused about pointers. `new(VirtualDevice)` returns a pointer to a newly created `VirtualDevice`, (so your `sensorData` is type `*VirtualDevice`). When you take `&sensorData` you are getting a pointer of that pointer. You don't often want to do that. You can leave the `&` off of passing it to `json.Unmarshal` and the return and change the return type.

Comment: Thank you. I am also trying to append the pointer to my VirtualDevice struct into a slice of pointers. However when I print out the first element of that slice, I get an empty JSON. Any ideas as to why that is?

Comment: `fmt.Println` doesn't print JSON. It converts values to string by various means. By default pointers are printed out as memory addresses. I'm not seeing the VD type in your example, but you can try adding a `func (vd *VD) String() string` to it and see if that changes your output.

Comment: It currently prints out this: `{{ } {[] {}}}` The problem is that it prints out before any information is filled. Is there any way I can tell the program to stall in my second file?